# Visual Studio not pulling Methods from WSDL Web Servie

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, wsdl

i am trying to add a web service into my C# project (Visual Studio 2013) , i have right clicked References->Add Service Reference->Advanced->Add Web Reference and added the WSDL file URL added the web reference name and then added the reference all goes well except none of the Service Methods are being created, i have tried numerous things but no luck , if i call the service in PHP all works well?

WSDL reference file : http://www.veriid.com/company_creditreport_api/Soap_server.php?wsdl

perhaps you could have a look and give me the answer?

thanks in advance